# JQL in JIRA Issue Navigator to retrieve Parent Issue with Separate Rows for Each Child and Their Created Dates

Tags: jira, jql

Is there a way to create a JQL for the separating related issues or linked issues in JIRA to separate rows and their dates as shown in the example below?

**Linked issue considered Hyperlink** in JIRA Issue Navigator and has the column name as **Links**. It will be converted to strings when exported as Excel file.

**Parent issue details:**

CX-1234

Created date: 11/12/2023

Resolved date: 20/12/2023

**Child tickets details:**

MR-2345

Created date: 12/12/2023

Resolved date: 16/12/2023

OP-4932

Created date: 14/12/2023

Resolved date: 18/12/2023

Currently:

| Key | Linked Issues | Created Date | Resolved Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CX-1234 | MR-2345,OP-4932 | 11/12/2023 | 20/12/2023 |

What I want:

| Key | Linked Issues | Created Date | Resolved Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CX-1234 | MR-2345 | 12/12/2023 | 16/12/2023 |
| CX-1234 | OP-4932 | 14/12/2023 | 18/12/2023 |

So far I  can view the parent CRs with their related issue or linked issues with no details for them (Just parent details). **Linked issue considered Hyperlink In JIRA Issues Navigator**